# Is Jesus the Father?

Tags: life-of-jesus, nature-of-god

I think that Jesus is the Father himself. The Father became man and as man he renounced his divinity, therefore there are Bible passages where it seems that Jesus is not God.
And that is why I don't believe that there is a Triune God.

This may be a ridiculous example, but when I play a video game and control a character, then I take on a new role, I who is in the real world is still me, but in the world of the game, I am another "person".
Maybe it's like Jesus, Jesus is the character of God in this world.
Is this way of thinking wrong?

Comment: Do you have a particular denomination in mind? The answer would vastly depend on denomination. Trinitarians (Catholics, Orthodox, Anglicans, Lutherans, etc) would vehemently disagree. Unitarians (e.g Oneness Pentecostals, etc) might agree to some extent

Comment: I have no denomination in mind and I do not want to belong to any denomination.

Comment: The problem is that here as a Q&A forum, there is no particular viewpoint and the answer to your question in particular depends on denomination perspective. E.g. the answer for a Catholic is definitely no and could provide many reasons from Scripture, etc why. Some unitarians might agree with you and likewise have sources that could back up their opinions.

Comment: But ultimately, most theological points don't really come down to a single verse or two (and it would help if you could outline at least some of the verses you have in mind that support your position) and they certainly don't come down to our individual opinion.

Comment: John 10:30 follows the same pattern as Genesis 2:24, if that's what you had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Let us answer your question as being about what most Christians believe.

The vast majority of Christians are Trinitarian. They believe that Jesus and the Father are separate (though both persons of God).

The main reason for this is the many occasions where Jesus refers to the Father as separate from himself (e.g. Mt 10:32, Mt 16:17, Mt 20:23, Mk 8:38, Mk 13:32,  Lk 10:22, Jn 1:14, Jn 3:25, Jn 16:32) and addresses the Father (e.g. Matthew 11:25, Mk 14:36, Lk 22:42, Lk 23, Jn 11:41, Jn 12, Jn 17).